# Form Validation using HTML Service in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

When using UiApp in GAS, form validation could be done on the client side using *ClientHandlers* . How can the same be done using HTMLService ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMLService lets you write client side code, i.e. normal javascript. So you can check using code on the client or on the server.   Details are here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#GoogleScriptAPI

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I am now validating forms using a Jquery validator. Can such validators be implemented on server side?

Comment: I suspect no. I would pass data from the client to the server for validation. Sounds like you should look at some of the tutorials.

Comment: Yeah...I am pretty new to apps script. I am still getting my hands dirty with it. The official documentation, though useful, lacks in-depth details. I would be glad if could point me towards some relevant tutorials with practical examples.

Comment: I guess you have seen these: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles I remember the HTML service tutorial was good.

Comment: @neel how did you achieved the jquery validation, I tried but its not accepting .. any lead?